# comments need for exporting android Sqlite DB to CSV

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, export

I am trying to export the SQLite db of the app to CSV file and store in SD card. The exporting method was defined in DBAdapter class as ExportToCSV. I have check that the app create a SQLite database successfully. However, when I try to call ExportToCSV using onPause method in MainActivity, the app can not response to export the database. Can you give me any comments on how to correct this code? I will appreciate your help!

My code is as follows:

```
public void ExportToCSV(Cursor c, String fileName) {       
       int rowCount = 0;  
       int colCount = 0;  
       FileWriter fw;  
       BufferedWriter bfw;  
       File sdCardDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
       File saveFile = new File(sdCardDir, fileName);  
       try {  
            rowCount = c.getCount();  
           colCount = c.getColumnCount();  
           fw = new FileWriter(saveFile);  
           bfw = new BufferedWriter(fw);  
           if (rowCount > 0) {  
               c.moveToFirst();  
               // write the colume title  
               for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {  
                   if (i != colCount - 1)  
                      bfw.write(c.getColumnName(i) + ',');  
                   else  
                      bfw.write(c.getColumnName(i));  
               }  
               // change the line
               bfw.newLine();  
               // write data
               for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {  
                   c.moveToPosition(i);  
                   Log.v("exporting data", "exportting" + (i + 1) + "line");  
                   for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {  
                       if (j != colCount - 1)  
                           bfw.write(c.getString(j) + ',');  
                       else  
                          bfw.write(c.getString(j));  
                   }  
                   // change line
                   bfw.newLine();  
               }  
           }
```

I use onPause in MainActivity.java to call ExportToCSV:

```
@Override
 protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    DBAdapter myDatabase=new DBAdapter(this);
    myDatabase.open();
    Cursor c=myDatabase.getAllgpspoint();
 // this method was defined in DBAdapter.java and returned a Cursor
    myDatabase.ExportToCSV(c, "IRI.csv");
    myDatabase.close();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "can not response to export"? Is any function *not* called? Do you get an exception?

Comment: It seems that ExportToCSV can not function although the app keep generating data. I run the app in my HTC status, and it showed that "Acitivity MainActivity (in application database) is not responding."

Answer (score 0):

You must close the file at the end.

```
bfw.close();
```